# changing the look of my NSIS

Tags: nsis

So after gettig my installer to do almost everything that I would like it to do I now need to change the look of the installer that you see on run. I am not sure how to do this. I know that it has to do with the MUI but not what part. Would you all be so kind as to help. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need basically to include `MUI.nsh` or preferably `MUI2.nsh` to redefine the gui layout, then you can tailor the interface to you needs by defining some macros.

The [Modern User Interface documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html) explain all the possible settings and also links to [several examples](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html#examples) that you should try to see what to integrate into your setup.

In your own NSIS distribution, these files are also installed in `Docs\Modern UI 2\` for the documentation and `Examples\Modern UI\` for the sample scripts.

Comment: Note to Seki and QA: Some stuff is mostly binary-only-accessable. For example, GUI / Window sizes and other Resources ( Manifested stuff, if I may :) ).

Comment: @HX_unbanned: Sure, I did not mean that you can customize everything just by macros (imagine that you want some non-square hollow windows or mimick the layout of some other installer) but that you can suit it among the possibilities planned by MUI authors: number and order of installer pages, choice of logos, ...